# Oculus Quest: how to detect recording / screenshot

Tags: android, streaming, screenshot, recording, oculusquest

Is there a way - either through the oculus SDK or the Android SDK, to detect when the user is recording, streaming or taking a screenshot via the built in features of the Oculus Quest 2?

If so, how can this be queried or a callback be set?

Comment: i need this answer as well, can anyone please answer it? there must be a way, thanks